# How to apply value_counts to a grouped object

Tags: python, pandas

I have table that looks like this:

```
userid purchase_date
     1 2016-08-01
     1 2016-08-02
     2 2016-08-01
     2 2016-08-01
     3 2016-08-01
     3 2016-08-02
     3 2016-08-03
```

I am keeping track of each user's purchase history (a user can purchase multiple times a day). Now， I want to find the earliest date that the user made a purchase, so I did this:

```
df.groupby(userid).purchase_date.transform(min)
```

Now, I have the earliest purchase date for each. The next thing that I want to do is to apply `value_count` on it. so I expect to see this:

```
userid earliest_purchase_date
     1 2016-08-01
     2 2016-08-01
     3 2016-08-01
```

Apply `value_counts` on `earliest_purcahse_date` to get:

```
2016-08-01 3
```

How can I do that? I don't know what to do after the transformation.

P.S. I tried `df.groupby(userid).purchase_date.transform(min).value_counts()` this operation is performed on the entire `df`, not on each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `groupby` with [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for get `indices` of minimal values per group with selecting by `loc`:

```
print (df.groupby('userid')['purchase_date'].idxmin())
userid
1    0
2    2
3    4
Name: purchase_date, dtype: int64

df = df.loc[df.groupby('userid')['purchase_date'].idxmin()]
print (df)
   userid purchase_date
0       1    2016-08-01
2       2    2016-08-01
4       3    2016-08-01
```

And last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (df.purchase_date.value_counts())
2016-08-01    3
Name: purchase_date, dtype: int64
```

If need count how many minimal values is per group:

```
df = df.groupby('userid')['purchase_date']
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([len(x[x == x.min()]),x.min()],index=['count','min date']))
       .unstack()
print (df)

       count             min date
userid                           
1          1  2016-08-01 00:00:00
2          2  2016-08-01 00:00:00
3          1  2016-08-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: I tried `idxmin()` but got an error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'`

Comment: What is `print (df.purchase_date.dtypes)` ? `datetime` or `object` ?

Comment: It is `dtype('O')`

Comment: Try convert first to datetime by `df.purchase_date = pd.to_datetime(df.purchase_date)`